# Font issue with Apportable

Tags: ios, fonts, cocos2d-iphone, apportable

Looks there is issue with fonts support when porting from Cocos2D IOS project using Apportable. If font extensions is written with capital letters like "cartoon.TTF" and then labels initialized with "cartoon.TTF" text will not be visible or will be used standard font instead of defined.

Would be nice to have font support no meter of letters case in apportable

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you should rename font extension to lower case letters like "cartoon.ttf" and change labels property to "cartoon.ttf".